# Trying to understand the syntax of delay function

Tags: javascript, callback

the delay function:Delays a function for the given number of milliseconds, and then calls it with the arguments supplied.

is written from underscore js. annotated source:

```
_.delay = function(func, wait) {
    var args = slice.call(arguments, 2);
    return setTimeout(function(){
      return func.apply(null, args);
    }, wait);
  };
```

for the delay function to work, why we need to use slice method and call (arguments,2), what does this part do? 
Please correct me if im wrong. the delay function first return setTimeout to perform the delay, and the setTimeout function return func.apply(null,args) to pass on all of the information from one function to another? but what is "null" doing here?

when we call a function using delay, it says:

```
var log = _.bind(console.log, console);
_.delay(log, 1000, 'logged later');
=> 'logged later' // Appears after one second.
```

im not sure how the optional argument 'logged later' works here since im not sure how bind method works here either? can you please give me a simpler example?

Comment: All it does is remove the two first arguments, the function and the time, and then it calls the passed in function after the given time, with any other arguments passed in after the first two.

Answer (score 0):

`setTimeout` executes code in `window` context, so you have to take care to provide the correct reference for `this` in the callback function. `_.bind` does it for you.

```
var MyObject = function() {

  this.myVariable = 'accessible';

  this.myMethod = function(message) {
    console.log((this === window));
    console.log(message + this.myVariable);
  }

}

var myObject = new MyObject();

// it will throw an error, because the this.myVariable isn't accessible
_.delay(myObject.myMethod, 1000, 'the correct scope is: ');

// this will be binded to the correct scope
_.delay(_.bind(myObject.myMethod, myObject), 1000, 'the correct scope is: ');
```